# How to create Odoo scheduler

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I want to make a modification on hr_holidays module to create a schedule every month to allocate 3 extra days for each employee.

By following this [tutorial](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/category/automated-actions/) I managed to create a single record for each employee which updates itself to add extra 3 days for each employee. Here's my code

class hr_holidays(models.Model):

```
_inherit = 'hr.holidays',

#This function is called when the scheduler goes off

def process_demo_scheduler_queue(self, cr, uid, context=None):

    scheduler_line_obj = self.pool.get('hr.holidays')

    #Contains all ids for the model hr.holidays

    scheduler_line_ids = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').search(cr, uid, [])   

    #Loops over every record in the model hr.holidays

    for scheduler_line_id in scheduler_line_ids :

    #Contains all details from the record in the variable scheduler_line

        scheduler_line =scheduler_line_obj.browse(cr, uid,scheduler_line_id ,context=context)

    number_of_days_temp = scheduler_line.number_of_days_temp

    state = scheduler_line.state

    #Prints out the name of every record.

    #Update the record

    scheduler_line_obj.write(cr, uid, scheduler_line_id, {'number_of_days_temp': (number_of_days_temp +3), 'state': 'confirm'}, context=context)
```

cron view:

```
<record id="ir_cron_scheduler_hr_holidays" model="ir.cron">

        <field name="name">Leaves scheduler</field>

        <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>

        <field name="interval_number">1</field>

        <field name="interval_type">months</field>

        <field name="numbercall">-1</field>

        <field eval="False" name="doall"/>

        <field eval="'hr.holidays'" name="model"/>

        <field eval="'process_demo_scheduler_queue'" name="function"/>

    </record>
```

But what I need is that I want to schedule every month with a new created record ea. each employee will have 12 allocation records in a single year, not only one record which update itself every month.

How to do that?

Comment: Firstly u can check the scheduled action  1 minutes,2minutes and 3 minutes and so if  will work in minutes interval then after u can go for the monthly and one more things the function which u are define into the scheduled action it is available in your model class or not.

Comment: I already tested it with 1 min interval. And yes, I've created a new  class of `class hr_holidays(models.Model):` which inherits the hr.holidays module ... the code is working fine, but instead of the `process_demo_scheduler_queue` function creates new allocation requests every 1 min it updates its own record. I want it every 1 min it create a new allocation request.

Comment: because of you are using write so record always do a write operation and create which use to create a new allocation request but you are not doing with the creation part in your process_demo_scheduler_queue function

Comment: Ok, so I need to use keyword create instead of write ?.. I tried to do it as     `scheduler_line_obj.create(cr, uid, scheduler_line_id, {'number_of_days_temp': (number_of_days_temp +3), 'state': 'confirm'}, context=context)` But I got an error, can you help me to write it down, cus I'm kind of new to Odoo.. Thank you

Comment: Yoooo welcom, create method having no ids will pass in its syntex no need to add the scheduler_line_id in your create method and more things u can try it will not done then feel free and send that code  and your related module on my mail : dasadiya.chaitanya@gmail.com I will fix for you :) :)

Comment: Change it to this: `scheduler_line_id = scheduler_line_obj.create(cr, uid, {'number_of_days_temp': (number_of_days_temp +3), 'state': 'confirm'}, context=context)`. `create` method returns `id` of the new created record.